# building a custom communication protocol in C++ for a distributed system

Tags: c++, networking, boost, netty, zeromq

I have a need to build a custom communication protocol in a distributed system. The logic on the individual nodes is implemented in C++.

In my past experience, when I had to do this thing in Java, I relied on Netty. Is there a similar framework/library in C++ that allows me to implement my own custom protocols?

I looked at `ZeroMQ` briefly. However, at the docs I found seem to over-emphasize on using the pred-defined patterns like **`REQ`**/**`REP`**, **`PUB`**/**`SUB`** etc. **Is there a more foundational layer** on ZeroMQ **that does not force me to use these patterns**, but still provides enough support to implement custom communication protocols?

If there are other libraries (heard of `Boost.Asio`) that are a better fit, then that is also welcome.

Comment: Asio is great, but it operates at the socket layer, it doesn't implement higher-level protocols. If you're fine with that, try Asio.

Comment: Not a solution for you, but the patterns you mention *are* the foundational layer of of ZMQ, you build the communication pattern you want with those tools... and its actually quite a powerful way to accomplish these sorts of tasks, but you have to understand it and buy into it, and if you already have an architecture that requires a more fundamental approach then it might not be for you.

Comment: nanomsg has compact interface for writing protocols. I wrote fusion of PUB/SUB and BUS for my needs. You can read details [here](http://vitiy.info/writing-custom-protocol-for-nanomsg/).

Answer (score 1):

`ZeroMQ` or `nanomsg` frameworks ( as cool, broker-less tools ) make you a great messaging IO layer and you may forget about their smart internalities.

You can do whatever procotol-abstraction on your own.

If you got an impression, that PUB/SUB is the focus of the ZeroMQ, seems you have missed their greatest powers.

Did you have a chance to read into any Pieters Hinjens' book on advanced design principles behind zero-copy, zero-energy, zero-sharing, zero-latency ;o) ?

Worth one's time. [More gems included.]

The very PROTOCOL oriented design approaches may help a lot in your `own-protocol`-FSA design & validation, the more if you strive for professional-grade, multi-threaded, heterogenous, distributed, scale-able, self-healing, fast, low-latency formal-communication-patterns.

Comment: Since I am most familiar with Netty, can you explain ZeroMQ in terms of Netty features? Are they at par with each other?

Comment: In particular, if I want to implement a Spdy like custom bidirectional duplex protocol on ZeromQ, is that possible?

Comment: @ajay In case one can define a complete (distributed per-se) Finite-State-Automaton for her/his protocol, ZeroMQ/nanomsg will not bother to seamlessly carry the IOs. As observed, **most of all mis-concepts are on the very FSA-design side, not on the communication/messaging layer**. Once asked to ".. explain ZeroMQ in terms of Netty features?" **forgive me to dare promise anybody to explain delicacies in French pronunciation in terms used in a morse-code alphabet**. The world of abstract thinking ( and design principles are pretty abstract )  simply does not work this way. **Pitty, but true.**

Comment: Which book of Peter were you refering to? He has written several books on ZeroMQ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into middlewares like CORBA (many different brokers are available, but I would not recommend use it), ICE from ZeroC, Protocol Buffers from Google, SOAP or even RPC. There are different pluses and minuses of using one or another, but I would recommend to use existing middleware, rather that develop your own. You can start here [middleware on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middleware_(distributed_applications)) and then decide which one is better for your needs.

Comment: ProtocolBuffer is a data protocol, not a communication protocol framework. I think you missed my question.